# JQuery ajax loader and browser caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery to load some data dynamically via ajax.  Whenever the user initiates the ajax request (i.e. clicks a button, or loads a page etc.), I display an ajax loader gif.  Once the ajax requests completes (or errors out) I hide the loader image.

This works great most of the time. But I noticed (in IE7 for instance) that ajax calls that get sent out on page load get cached (I think).  So basically when I refresh the page and the ajax call is presumably fired out, IE will load up the cached data instead.  As a result, the success (or error) callback in the jquery `.ajax()` function never gets called and the loader image stays on indefinitely.  Whats the best way around this?

Comment: "... the ajax call is presumably fired...", I suggest you try this on firefox with firebug on it. It would a clearer picture of whats going on. Also if you are performing a GET with restful URL as compared to POST (which are not cached) you may encounter the issue of cache values being returned.

Comment: well i'm not seeing the same results in firefox. I can only reproduce this in IE..is there something like firebug for IE?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable ajax result caching across your entire site, use [.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

```
$.ajaxSetup( { cache : false } );
```

You can then override the behavior on a case by case basis with:

```
$.ajax ({ 
...
cache: true,
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`.ajax()` offers the `cache` property which is `true` by default:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   cache:  false
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As an alternative you could add a random number into your request query string.

```
$.ajax({
   url:   '/path/script.pl',
   dataType: 'text',
   type: 'GET',
   data: {
     q:   ~~(Math.random()*200)
   },
   success: function(data){
      // data
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ajax` actually has a built-in option to avoid exactly this:

```
$.ajax( { cache : false } );
```

The documentation is included with the ajax method: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

*From documentation:*

```
cache
Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
If set to false it will force the pages that you request to not be cached by the browser.
```